# How do I pass a custom python pdf viewer into PQYT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would like to embed a PDFViewer (https://github.com/Zain-Bin-Arshad/pdf-viewer) into PYQT5 . I was able to embed mathplotlib viewer by passing the canvas into SetCentralWidget. This doesnt seem to work with PDFViewer since I am guessing it isnt a widget? How to accomplish this?

```
import sys
from view import PDFViewer
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        v=PDFViewer()                                 #Create Instance of PDFViewer and put in a form that can be passed into PYQT5
        self.setCentralWidget(v)                      #pass into setCentralWidget
        self.show()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

I tried the variations of the code above and I get the the pdfviewer and the mainwindow separately..

Comment: That program uses PySimpleGui, which is a higher level library that is able to work with different toolkits. That viewer is probably a "wrapper" around a "virtual" widget, not a proper Qt widget. Unfortunately, PSG doesn't seem to provide a comprehensive API for its "widgets", so I suggest you to write to the author of that viewer and eventually contact the PSG staff.

Comment: Another possible complication is I am using PyQt5 and PySimpleGui uses Pyside. Looks like creating a PDFviewer with PyQtWebEngine much better route. Thank you

Comment: PySimpleGui *is* able to use PyQt just like PySide. The problem is that there seems to be no clear way to "force" a specific library. Remember that the aim of PSG is to create an abstraction layer of the toolkit (no matter which one) allowing *simple* UI creation. If you want to use full Qt capabilities, using such a "simplification" might actually result in complicating things. Despite the further dependency (and memory requirements), the QtWebEngine module will probably a better and more reliable choice. (Note, it's QtWebEngine, not PyQtWebEngine: PyQt, just like PySide, is a *binding*).